# Could not find method android () for arguments [build...] on root project, also can't build gradle projects and can't find the debug keystore

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am trying to find the debug keystore using android studio gradle method and command line method but to no avail. When I try to sync or build the gradle project, a error "Could not find method android () for arguments [build...] on root project.." appears.

Anyone has any idea on how to solve the build for gradle and also to find the debug keystore?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/88oeqaq3ynw1707/android%20studio.png?dl=0

Comment: This looks like you have your project gradle mixed with your app gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the `android { ... }` code in `app` `build.gradle` and not in top level `build.gradle`.

Remove the `android { .. }` and `dependencies { ... }` block from the GrowMoney `build.gradle` and add in `app\build.gradle`.

Comment: Thanks. The above problem is .solved. But now i am getting “Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found”. I have updated the gradle distribution version in gradle wrapper properties but to no avail. Do I need to write the build gradle dependencies somewhere?

Comment: I suppose it would be better if you post that as a separate question with necessary code -- all your `build.gradle` files and the error report. If this solution solved the above problem in the question, please upvote/ mark this as correct.